# Default Encoding and changes

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, utf-8

By default, `Character` and `String` use UTF-16, however, for all practical purposes, in North America and most of the english locales, UTF-8 is sufficient (since it can go upto 4 bytes). So, if I use a `InputStreamReader(InputStream)`, then does it give me default UTF-16 `char` encoding? Using a `InputStreamReader(InputStream, "UTF-8")` would provide a UTF-8 encoding, which would suffice my purpose.

How can I auto-set my JVM's default encoding to UTF-8 while using English locale? The intention is to improve performance for `Character` and `String` manipulation (by using 8-bit scheme instead of 16-bit encoding and most ASCII is covered using 8-bit encoding and at the same time complying with Unicode standard).

Any comments are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am no expert on the actual runtime environment's way of handling strings but I don't think its possible to change that, unless you wish to create your own implementations of a UTF-8 string class. N.B: By supplying UTF-8 into the InputStreamReader constructor you do not change the way native java (char) objects and String are handled, you merely change how the input data is parsed. The data will be held as UTF-16 in RAM regardless of how you manipulate it.

Comment: @CPUTerminator, thanks for your useful comment. Do you know what is the encoding for a java class file? Is it UTF-8 to save space?

Comment: The 'encoding' of the class file can be changed through different compiler options. If you use an IDE, it should be available somewhere in the build properties.

Comment: @CPUTerminator, If its always 16-bit natively to JAVA, then does it even make sense to set another encoding on InputStreamReader for efficiency purpose? I would understand that it does make sense on the OutputStreamWriter. Your thoughts!!

Comment: It wouldn't be a efficiency thing. If your input source was encoded in UTF-16 setting the charset encoding to UTF-8 will cause the parsed data to be invalid. Similarly, if the data was UTF-8 and you set the charset encoding to UTF-16, it will try to read two distinctive characters as one symbol. The character encoding parameter for input streams is not meant to be optional, as it has a big effect on how the data is treated, thus the basic problem here is not efficiency but rather correctness.

Comment: Ah! that clarifies it further. So, in case of encoding/decoding character sets, it more of correctness than efficiency. I will keep that in mind. Thanks again.

Comment: When encoding for storage, you can consider storing in UTF-8 rather than UTF-16 (A java writer object that takes a charset will convert appropriately) as this will be more space efficient, like you said yourself in an earlier comment. Other than this there isn't much else you can do with charsets that promote any sort of performance improvement.

Comment: You should be treating all strings as byte arrays in UTF-8 anyway. Read http://utf8everywhere.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, if I use a InputStreamReader(InputStream), then does it give me
>   default UTF-16 char encoding? Using a InputStreamReader(InputStream,
>   "UTF-8") would provide a UTF-8 encoding, which would suffice my
>   purpose.
>
> How can I auto-set my JVM's default encoding to UTF-8 while using
>   English locale?

From `InputstreamReader` java DOC:

> The charset that InputStreamReader uses may be specified by name or
>   may be given explicitly, or **the platform's default charset may be
>   accepted**.

like when i try to print in my platform using `reader.getEncoding()`; it prints `UTF-8`. Java gets character encoding by calling `System.getProperty("file.encoding")` at the time of JVM start-up. So if Java doesn't get any file.encoding attribute it uses `"UTF-8"` character encoding for all practical purpose. However to set encoding to the JVM instance, one can use `System.setProperty("file.encoding, "UTF-16"")`.

[Here is a useful article with more details.](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/get-set-default-character-encoding.html)

Comment: you have brought a great point. So, if I set system property using your code, then do I still have to do a InputStreamReader(InputStream, "UTF-8")? If I call System.setProperty("file.encoding","UTF-8") once at the program start up, then does it become global default for that JVM instance?

Comment: I also intended to ask you, that after setting System.setProperty("file.encoding","UTF-8"), its only the data manipulation that is UTF-8, but actually, natively, JAVA again would use a UTF-16, no matter what. So, if I want to use UTF-32, then Do i have to again do a InputStreamReader(InputStream, "UTF-32")? I think the answer may be obvious but it would be a great if you can confirm

Comment: for 1 Q: No, if you set system property you won't have to set it in reader constructor for the JVM instance you set.

for 2 Q: [check this article once i bookmarked.](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/get-set-default-character-encoding.html)

Comment: thanks again. very useful link. One more question, Do you know what is the encoding for a java class file? Is it UTF-8 to save space?

Comment: As much as i know it is "UTF-8"

Comment: But the correct answer you would get from [wikipedia of java class file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file)

Comment: i found this link which is clearly saying its 8-bit. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html

Comment: Try the page for [Java7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html)

Comment: do you know if java uses System.getProperty("file.encoding","UTF-8")? from one of the links that you pasted above. I couldnt find even in the C source code. It seems JAVA always is dynamically using the platform to retrieve the value for default encoding. So, it cant be UTF-8 if nothing is found. Pls. suggest your thoughts.

Comment: java uses System.getProperty("file.encoding") at the time JVM start up. If no file encoding is found it uses "utf-8" as i have already said. Strings internally are stored as chars, which a unsigned 16 bit integers representing UTF-16 code points but externally, as for serialization as a byte stream, JAVA by default use the platform
default charset.

Answer (score 4):

The in-memory data types for text in java, char, Character, and String, are UTF-16. Absolutely. Always. Unconditionally.

The only thing you can change is how Java converts from bytes-on-the-outside to chars-on-the-inside. There is no way to change the representation to UTF-8 to trade space for time.

Comment: @bmarguiles, thanks. This helps. The conversion is only for parsing of data but not how it is held.

Comment: Do you know what is the encoding for a java class file? Is it UTF-8 to save space?

Comment: If its always 16-bit natively to JAVA, then does it even make sense to set another encoding on InputStreamReader for efficiency purpose? I would understand that it does make sense on the OutputStreamWriter. Your thoughts!!

Comment: It's nothing to do with efficiency. The reader encoding is necessary to tell it _the format of the bytes on the disk_.